# How do I copy existing files and create a duplicate files using xcopy?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I can't seem to find a way to copy an existing file but I do not want to let the previous file with the same name get overwritten. Let say I want to copy data.txt from various pc's by using batch file but I do not want "data.txt" gets overwritten, instead is there a way for the command to generate automated filename to avoid it from overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "/-y" switch to confirm before copying a duplicate file.

> /-y : Prompts to confirm that you want to overwrite an existing
>   destination file.

The entire list of switches can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but thats not the solution that I seek for. I want to copy the file but with both existing files and the new file exist in the same folder, only the name of the file is different

Comment: See the following - http://superuser.com/questions/467755/command-script-to-copy-files-with-certain-ext-which-may-have-the-same-name-fro

Comment: Np, if you found the answer useful you can accept it!